# pyramid_formalchemy assumptions about requests

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using pyramid_formalchemy 0.4.1...well I'm trying to use it.

When requests come in to my app I keep seeing pyramid_formalchemy making strange assumptions about what will be in the request object.  My requests fail because in pyramid_formalchemy.views (starting at line: 58) the ModelView class has a constructor with the following code:

```
def __init__(self, context, request):
    self.context = context
    self.request = request
    self.session = request.session_factory

    self.fieldset_class = request.forms.FieldSet
    self.grid_class = request.forms.Grid
```

The thing is my request object has a 'session' not a 'session_factory'.  It also doesn't have 'forms'

Here is what I've done:

1. Create a RootFactory that extends pyramid_formalchemy.resources.Models
2. I call config.formalchemy_admin() passing it my RootFactory and my DBSession
3. I created an empty forms.py file.

What am I missing in my setup?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is configurable.

See the [source](https://github.com/FormAlchemy/pyramid_formalchemy/blob/master/pyramid_formalchemy/__init__.py#L48)

Not sure it's really documented..

Comment: Yeah, I've done a lot of tweaking and looking at source, that's what got my as far as I am at this point.  Still never figured out why it's expecting special things from my session though, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Oh, I wanted to add, in the link you sent...there are 3 factory parameters (poorly named).  'factory' refers to an ACL factory, 'session' refers to a DBSession and 'query_factory' is a factory for creating DB queries.  None of these have anything to do with the HTTP request, or HTTP session that pyramid_sqlalchemy is making assumptions about.  I'm puzzled.